# I must be completely misunderstanding Mirror, because it doesn't seem to do anything?

Tags: mirror

As you can see I've got a procedurally constructed cylinder here, and I've turned on Mirror along every global axis and... nothing.

[image]

My expectation here is that selecting "Mirror along X axis" with my construct selected should create a second cylinder below the X-Y plane, and enabling all 3 axis of symmetry as I've done here should create a bunch more mirrors of this thing.

But instead, there's absolutely no impact on my file as far as I can tell, I've looked all around for mirrored cylinders and there's none. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: It’s across the Y-Z plane rather. X is red, Y is green, Z is blue and is the vertical.

Answer (score 6):

The red and green lines you see are the world X, Y axes. The local axes go through the little orange dot marking the object's origin. Move your object in *Edit Mode* and everything will become clear:

[image]

You can add an empty in the middle and use it in the *Mirror* modifier [image] to get the intended result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the blender user guide, the mesh->mirror option found in edit mode is "exactly equivalent to scaling vertices by -1 around one chosen pivot point and in the direction of one chosen axis, only it is faster/handier."

I see from your image that you have the transform mode set to median point of selected, so any mirroring will be done around the center of all vertices you have selected. I can't see if any vertices are selected, but it appears you have a cylinder, which is completely symmetric.

In order to see a difference, first add some asymmetry to your mesh. Then making sure all of the vertices are selected in edit mode, apply the mesh -> mirror operator. You will see the selected vertices mirror around their overall center along the axis you selected.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your mirror configuration as the object is selected in the right hand pane rather than the modifier tab.

You are also in edit mode which can affect mirror display.

In order to explore the mirror modifier, open a new general where you have a cube at 0,0,0 co-ordinates. The "origin" of the cube is in the centre and mirror uses the origin as the "mirror" if not otherise defined.

Edit the cube and select and delete five of the six faces leaving just the front face.

Go back to object mode and add a mirror modifier. Try the Y axis first.

Go back to edit mode and move the face around to see the effect.

Now try the other axis and move the plane around to see what happens remembering that the mirror plane is at the origin of the object.